# Splitting people into two teams having the graph of relationships

Tags: algorithm, graph

we have `n` players, some of these players are friends ( if John is a friend of Sara, then Sara is a friend of John too). We want to split these players into two teams ( a team can also be empty!). If all players in a team are friends and every player on the other team are enemies (not friends) of the players, then that team can win the game. Given a graph with `n` vertices and `m` edges (every edge shows a friendship), how can I check whether we can split the vertices to get a winning team or not?

Comment: Feels like something is missing. Because this is too trivial. Just put 2 friends in one team, then everyone in this team are friends, and therefore they can win.

Comment: @yemre well, actually it's even more trivial than that. The empty team is winning. And so is a team with one player. So there isn't even  the need to find two people who are friends ^^

Comment: @Paul, yes you are right. I guess I was trying to give a more "natural" example. But of course teams with one or zero players also win according to the asker's definition.

Comment: @yemre OP hasn't mentioned it, but the team size has to be ```n/2``` for the question to make sense

Comment: @Paul sorry I forgot to mentione that every body on the other team should not be friends, edited the question

Comment: A very plausible result would be a non-connected node that is in his team and that node "wins" the game...

Comment: Should the teams be the same size? And should the other team have no "internal" friends, too? What if there are two or more "winning" teams?

Comment: Are you checking that the players of the losing team are not friends with the players of the winning team, or not friends between themselves? Because in this graph `*-* *-*` (4 vertices 2 edges 2 connected components) there are two teams that are fully connected and have no outside connections.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for parts of the graph where (a) each node is connected to each other node, and (b) no node is connected to a node outside of that part. The easiest and fastest way should be to turn those two steps around, i.e. find connected components of the graph, and then see if those components are fully connected. The first part is a simple Depth-First-Search, and for the second part you just have to count edges.

1. get any node from the graph that is not yet part of a component
2. from that node, do a Depth-First-Search to find all nodes in the component this node is part of
3. check whether the component is fully connected, i.e. each node in the component has an edge to each other node, i.e. each node has `k-1` edges and there are `k(k-1)/2` edges in total, `k` being the size of the component; if so, this component is a "winning team"
4. if there are unvisited nodes left, continue with step (1)

The total complexity should be `O(n)`, `n` being the number of nodes in the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you're looking for [cliques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem).

Our winning team must be a clique in the original graph (they are all friends of each other). Once a clique is found, you'll need to check that this clique is not connected to the rest of the graph.

Psudo code:

```
allCliques = getAllCiques(originalGraph)
for each clique of allCliques {
  foundOutsideConnection = false
  for each node of clique {
    if (node is connected to any node outside the clique) {
      foundOutsideConnection = true
    }
  }
  if not foundOutsideConnection {
    print(clique)
  }
}
```

Comment: Might be faster the other way around: Find connected components, then check whether any of those is fully connected.

Comment: @tobias_k how would you define these connected components?

Comment: Just do a Depth-First-Search and all the nodes you reach are in one component. Check if all the nodes are connected (basically just if all the nodes have as many edges as there are nodes in the group minus one), then continue with the rest of the graph. Should be O(n) this way.

Comment: @tobias_k - that's a good point. Write that up an answer